# Angular nameless ng-app

Tags: angularjs

How and why is `<body ng-app>` used? How can we assign controllers, directives etc to this nameless module. Also explain how this is related to manually bootstraping the Angular App.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbvnfb1j/)

Comment: angular's default directive is `ng-app`. You can assign a module name if you want to but if you use only `ng-app` angular will initialize your module.

Comment: It's the equivalent of ng-app=""

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ng-app without a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622133/using-ng-app-without-a-value)

Answer (score 3):

This is actually three separate questions, but I'm happy to tackle each one.

- How and why is  used?

Angular will not and cannot properly bootstrap the application unless there is an entrance point to that application.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp), if a parameter is not passed that names the app instance, angular will attempt to [auto-bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) the application for you by crawling the DOM and using the first ngApp directive instance that it is encountered.

We typically want to place our entrance point on the `<body>` element to encompass all the potential DOM we need without cluttering it with `<head>` elements, such as loading scripts and css.  That said, if you are auto-bootstrapping your application, the recommended placement is on the HTML element.

- How can we assign controllers, directives etc to this nameless module?

Modules, controllers, etc MUST be attached to *something* in order for Angular to pick them up and interopt with them correctly.

Once the application is bootstrapped, Angular will begin parsing the DOM, looking for directives.  If you have an application instance (and you do), your controllers will be automatically be added to that instance.  If you look at the [bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) documentation -> Automatic Initialization, you'll find the following:

> Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when
>   the angular.js script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState
>   is set to 'complete'. At this point Angular looks for the ng-app
>   directive which designates your application root. If the ng-app
>   directive is found then Angular will:
>
> - load the module associated with the directive.
> - create the application
> - injector compile the DOM treating the ng-app directive as the root of
>     the compilation. This allows you to tell it to treat only a portion of
>     the DOM as an Angular application.

- How the heck is the fiddle working?

This one is actually smoke and mirrors that really shouldn't count :).  If you look at the network traffic for JSFiddle, you'll find that AngularJS is actually being loaded.  As a result, your interpolation is actually getting automagically bound to the ***JSFiddle*** Angular instance, not one that you provide yourself (or in this case didn't), parsed, and subsequently rendered into the DOM as `2`.

Comment: even controllers after angular 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Per angularjs.org:

> "The ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the  or  tags."

In other words, `ng-app` is what makes your html become an Angular application, thus being able to use the `{{ }}` in your code. These brackets are able to carry out operations, which is why you're able to calcuate 1 + 1. If you were to use variables, however, you would need to attach an `ng-controller` to a container div and initialize a Controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's the equivalent of `ng-app=""`. However, you need a namespace to attach controllers, directives. etc too. Angular can interpolate `{{ 1 + 1 }}` without a namespace, but you won't be able to bind anything to the views scope. Interestingly enough `ng-app=" "` is a namespace you can bind to.

https://jsfiddle.net/n3hygcnd/3/

Comment: Fun fact: you can bind to `ng-app="undefined"` too, which isn't that interesting unless you consider the following:

`angular.module(void 0, []) === angular.module()`