# Unable to get binding value displayed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I started with AngularJS, but am unable to get the desired output. Here's the code.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/todo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <h2>Total todos: {{totalTodos}}</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                {{todo.text}}

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

todo.js

```
function TodoCtrl($Scope) {
    $Scope.totalTodos = 4;
    $scope.todos = [
        { text: 'Learn AngularJS', done: false },
        { text: 'Build an appp', done: false }
    ];
}
```

Comment: This is the output that I am getting.

Total todos: {{totalTodos}}

Comment: where's your code for declaring controllers and application module?

Comment: As mentioned above you need the var app = angular.module not quite sure what the code is I'm on mobile.

Comment: It's solved guys, Thank you for your input :)

Comment: @WaqasAhmad : All the answers are correct, you can mark anyone as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the module and controller code for angular(basic example link http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/VeQbrW ). You could place the following code in your todo.js file. I have placed some comment in the code to show additional changes I made to your posted code to make it work.

In the following example you will notice that I place the ng-app attribute inside the oppening tag of a div. This is because I do not have access to the html tag in code pen. The way you are attempting to do it in your html code is correct. The only thing you are missing is the value.

Live Example: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/WrMZxg

Angular Controller Code:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  //changed from $Scope.totalTodos = 4 (syntax error $Scope would be undefined)
  $scope.totalTodos = 4;

    $scope.todos = [
        { text: 'Learn AngularJS', done: false },
        { text: 'Build an appp', done: false }
    ];

}]);
```

You will also need to add an app name to your ng-app attribute.

Example: `<html ng-app="app">`

Fully corrected HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/todo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <h2>Total todos: {{totalTodos}}</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                {{todo.text}}

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Additional HTML example using ng-bind attribute:

```
      <!--Example using ng-bind-->
      <h1>Example using ng-bind<h1>


    <h2>Total todos:<span ng-bind="totalTodos"></span></h2>

        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-bind="todo.text">


            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help answer your question. You could also use ng-bind instead of the {{statement goes here}}. I know sometimes if the page takes a bit to load you may see the {(statement goes here}} before angular renders it to the screen, ng-bind will hide it until it is loaded.  I will add it my code pen example if you want to check it out.

Comment: Thank you once again. Hoping to see your valuable inputs in future as well. Regards

Comment: Not a problem, I will help anytime I can, I updated my answer with the ng-bind attribute I was talking about. I hope you enjoy learning angular. Here is a link to some examples I have on codepen http://codepen.io/collection/ABNPEB/  There is basic template and some other examples you might find helpful as you progress in your learning.

Comment: I'll check all of them as I have a complete project to make using angular. :)

Comment: Good luck, my website with my email is on my code pen profile so if you get in a real bind you can shoot me an email and I will try and help out when time permits.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this**

```
$Scope
```

**To this**

```
$scope
```

**Also you need**

ng-app="app" which is your module name, i believe you haven't defined your module

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/todo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <h2>Total todos: {{totalTodos}}</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                {{todo.text}}

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**todo.js**

```
angular.module("app", []).controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {  
  $scope.totalTodos = 4;

    $scope.todos = [
        { text: 'Learn AngularJS', done: false },
        { text: 'Build an appp', done: false }
    ];

}]);
```

**Further info you can get here**

[Using ng-app without a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30622342/419956)

Comment: See [this (decent) explanation of why you sometimes see `ng-app` without   a value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30622342/419956) in examples, and why you actually kind-of *need* to name your module.

Comment: That was prior to 1.3 If you execute same code with latest you will get "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SomeController' is not a function, got undefined". It's always better to answer as recommended by latest versions.

Comment: Thank you. 
Checking the example now. Thanks :)

Comment: @PratapA.K You mistook my intention. I just meant to explain to OP *why* your answer suggests that naming the module is a good thing (when OP might still see old pre-1.3 examples leading him to believe otherwise). As in, you might consider adding the link I provided in your answer as a "further reading" thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your todo.js contains a casing issue in the second line replace '$Scope' with  '$scope'. your code works once I corrected that and include module if you haven't declared already like i mentioned in below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">

<head>
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/todo.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
 <h2>Total todos: {{totalTodos}}</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                {{todo.text}}

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApp",[])
        .controller("TodoCtrl",function($scope){
           $scope.totalTodos = 4;
    $scope.todos = [
        { text: 'Learn AngularJS', done: false },
        { text: 'Build an appp', done: false }
    ];

        });
    </script>
</body>
```