# AngularJS - An App With No Name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This reminds me of an old song:

"You see I've been reading samples of an app with no name..."

I'd better stop or I'll hear from Neil Young's lawyers.

I am studying AngularJS on W3Schools and in some of their examples the ng-app attribute is an empty string.  In others it has a name for the app.  It seems that when there is no name there is also no controller function defined in the client script and the application is automatically wired up from the HTML.  But in those examples if I enter a name in the ng-app tag it breaks the page.  So that raises two questions:

1 - What's the difference between having an ng-app tag with a name and one with an empty string?  Does no name mean no controller function is defined?

2 - Is it bad to have an ng-app with no name?  Should I always name my ng-app and load it with a controller function?

"...it felt good to be out from the rain."

Edit: Looking at the alternate question "Using ng-app without a value", it is similar, but it doesn't directly address my question. It asks: How to use ng-app without a value. I'm asking for someone to explain: What is the difference between using ng-app with a value and without a value.

Comment: can you link that tutorial? and nice setup...now that song is in my head!

Comment: And I want to play GTA San Andreas now.  Thanks :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ng-app without a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622133/using-ng-app-without-a-value)

Comment: Jordan - the tutorial link is http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp They have a bunch.

Comment: Looking at the alternate question "Using ng-app without a value", it is similar, but it doesn't directly address my question.  It asks: How to use ng-app without a value.  I'm asking for someone to explain: What is the difference between using it with a value and without a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points here:

1. Recommend the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) because the author is the person knows the framework the best.
2. There are two ways to [bootstrap the angular apps](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap): automatically and manually
   when you use with `ng-app="appName"`, angularjs will automatically find the element with the tag 'ng-app' and initialize the application.

   when you ignore the `ng-app`, you need to bootstrap the app yourself:

.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

3. recommend always bootstrap app with either manual or auto.

===EDIT===

To be clearer :

4. The [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622133/using-ng-app-without-a-value) given by @Animal2 has very good explanation. In a short, before angular version 1.3, you can use `ng-app` as DOM element attribute without any value, because angularjs will handle everything else for you

:

```
<div ng-app>
    ....
</div>
```

but after version 1.3 it is NOT recommended to use this syntax. Instead you can use the 'auto' way and 'manual' way mentioned earlier.

Comment: Those are good links.  However, the example of manually initializing Angular looks different than what they are doing in (some of) the W3 Schools samples.  They have an empty ng-app attribute.  The link above has no ng-app attribute in the manual example.  That's also a little puzzling to me.

Comment: @SteveGaines I think it is better to always declare the 'ng-app' which is similar to always declare a variable before use in any language. Another point here, for bigger web-app, when you need to have more than one angular apps on the same app, 'manual' bootstrap is the ONLY way to make it work (from my work experience).

Answer (score 1):

> You can specify an AngularJS module to be used as the root module for the application. This module will be loaded into the $injector when the application is bootstrapped. It should contain the application code needed or have dependencies on other modules that will contain the code. See angular.module for more information.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Someone has already asked this question

[Using ng-app without a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622133/using-ng-app-without-a-value)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at the answers on that other question.

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't exactly 'incorrect' to have an empty `ng-app`, it is not recommended and won't work for even a slightly complex app. Think of it as a way to show whip up something quickly.

If there is no `ng-app` specified, it only means that there is no module to assign controllers (and whatever else you want) to, but as you can see it does still work... for the time being.