# How to hide a div using ng-hide in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The following code is not hiding span, How can i hide the span.i am asking this question as i am new to angularjs.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
$scope.myVar=true;
</script>


<body ng-app="" >

<span ng-hide="myVar">
<a href="adminPage">Click here for admin role</a>
</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Go through the angularjs tutorials. You need to define a controller and then use that controller in your view.

Answer (score 2):

You need a module first, then a controller or a directive.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
$scope.myVar = true;
});
</script>


<body ng-controller="myController">

<span ng-hide="myVar">
<a href="adminPage" ng-click"myVar = !myVar">Click here for admin role</a>
</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bootstrapped your application properly to make it an Angular app.

1. You need to create a main module
2. You need to attach the main module to the shell/index.html
3. You need a Controller to perform data-binding, user interactions, etc

You need to write your very first "Hello, World!" app using AngularJS as it very common writing a "Hello, World!" application when you're getting started with any technology.

`ng-app` directive is used to define the part of the HTML which will be an Angular app, it's value is an optional application module name to load. See this post about [using-ng-app-without-a-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622133/using-ng-app-without-a-value)

Show or hide content using Angular 1.0.1 **without specifying the main module** in the `ng-app` directive

```js
//angular
  //.module('demo', [])
  //.controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

//DefaultController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function DefaultController($scope) {
  $scope.isAdmin = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <span ng-show="isAdmin">
      <a href="#">Click here for admin role</a>
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="isAdmin">
      <a href="#">Click here for user role</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check the below example **using $scope object** to show or hide content by specifying the main module.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

DefaultController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function DefaultController($scope) {
  $scope.isAdmin = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <span ng-show="isAdmin">
      <a href="#">Click here for admin role</a>
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="isAdmin">
      <a href="#">Click here for user role</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check the below example using **controller aliasing syntax**, to show or hide content by specifying the main module.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.isAdmin = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <span ng-show="ctrl.isAdmin">
      <a href="#">Click here for admin role</a>
    </span>
    <span ng-hide="ctrl.isAdmin">
      <a href="#">Click here for user role</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```