# Problem of using ng-app directives in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm learning AngularJS from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp).

In [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_repeat_array), the app is working fine but if I give any name to ng-app then it is not working. Why is this happening? And how to debug the AngularJS code because sometimes it gives no error to the console.

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp. That's all we can do with what you posted. Are you aware that AngularJS is basically a dead framework, that will stop to be maintained in a few months?

Comment: Thank You JB Nizet, But why You say that " AngularJS is basically a dead framework".

Comment: Because it is. Google will stop maintaining it in a few months. https://blog.angular.io/stable-angularjs-and-long-term-support-7e077635ee9c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **ngApp** is an optional application module name to load.

You can read more about [ngApp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).

> The **angular.module** is a global place for creating, registering and
>   retrieving AngularJS modules. All modules (AngularJS core or 3rd
>   party) that should be available to an application must be registered
>   using this mechanism.

You can read more about [angular.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module).

If you don't specify **ng-app**, you'll not be able to use services, directives, controllers, filters, and configuration information. If you just leave it like **ng-app** or **ng-app=""**, then you'll just get basic angular functions to work.

And take a look at [Using ng-app without a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622133/using-ng-app-without-a-value).